# Android NDK: build after added a new library module directly under jni/ folder

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, multiple-makefiles

In my Android NDK project, I used to have only **one** library module:

```
jni/    
  Android.mk
  ...            (more source files)
```

Then, I need to add another new library module, which has no connection with the existing library module. I mean they are independent. I directly added the new library under `jni/` folder.

```
jni/    
  Android.mk
  ...            (more source files)

  new-lib/
     Android.mk
      ...            (more source files)
```

**Question 1:**
I run `ndk-build` command under my Android project to build. But **new-lib** is not built at all. Is that because I need to declare the `new-lib` module in the **Android.mk** under **jni/** folder ? If so, how to declare ?

**Question 2:**  when I load the new-lib (suppose the module name is "newlib"), should I use

`System.loadLibrary("new-lib/newlib");`

or just

`System.loadLibrary("newlib");` ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't run `android-ndk` command, you run `ndk-build` command.

**Question 1:**

You can tell your top level `Android.mk` i.e. $PROJECT/jni/Android.mk to include another `Android.mk` that are located in different places/sub-directories.

If you have defined any `Android.mk` files in sub-directories, you have to include them explicitly in your top-level `Android.mk`. There is a helper function for that

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Just add it in your top-level `Android.mk` file. This will include all the `Android.mk` files from sub-directories of the current file's path.

**Question 2:**

```
use System.loadLibrary("newlib");
```

No need to specify path.

Comment: Hi, I tried the include $(call all-subdir-makefiles) , my new-lib isn't built still. I am using ndk-build command

Comment: please edit the question and add source of Android.mk from both parent and sub-folders.